# Android Application crashes in while loop

Tags: java, android, json, while-loop, android-volley

I have an android app connected with my database using volley/JSON.I want to check continuously  the table "request" of a user in my database and when it has a value equal to 1 I want an alert message.I used while loop to handle it but the application crashes.Any ideas how to avoid using while?
Here is my java code I run into the mainactivity in onCreate method:

```
     while(request!=1)  {

        Response.Listener<String> response1Listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final String response) {


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);


                    request= jsonResponse.getInt("request");
                    requestorigin=jsonResponse.getString("requestorigin");

                     //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Request from    " + requestorigin ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Request from    " + request ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(request==1)  {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Request from    " + requestorigin ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (
                        JSONException e
                        )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        CheckRequest checkRequest = new CheckRequest(username,response1Listener);
        RequestQueue queue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        queue1.add(checkRequest);
    }
```

And here is the CheckRequest class:

```
package com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CheckRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://xxxxx.com/CheckRequest.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public CheckRequest(String username, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username  );
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

The logcat shows this:

```
29582-29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing 
opcode 0x6f at 0x120b 05-21 12:38:17.236 29582-    
29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 
'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method 
com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo.MainActivity.access$super 05-21 
12:38:17.236 29582-29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: 
unable to resolve check-cast 222 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in 
Lcom/example/sakis/multiplayerdemo/MainActivity;
```

Comment: 29582-29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x120b
05-21 12:38:17.236 29582-29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo.MainActivity.access$super
05-21 12:38:17.236 29582-29582/com.example.sakis.multiplayerdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 222 (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;) in Lcom/example/sakis/multiplayerdemo/MainActivity;

Comment: It runs perfectly if i replace the while loop with an if and check it only one time

Comment: It better to edit your post and add the log there, it's more readable

Comment: But what is the concrete exception?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the while loop is spinning waiting for `request` to change, which only happens in the response listener. The listener is called asynchronously, so you are effectively blocking your main thread and repeatedly queueing the same request.

Comment: Do you think is better to run the while-loop in the CheckRequest.php file and just waitng for the response?

Comment: No, don't run a while loop at all waiting for responses. Deal with them as asynchronous events.

Comment: And how can i do that?